# How to change an integer inside a file without coping the file to another

Tags: c, structure, file-handling, overwrite, fseek

I'm making a program for school where i have to create a function for making exams and another one to get the exam.
I did the part to create the exam. Now I'm trying to make the part to get the exam. The problem i have in this part is to store the points that are taken from the exam in the student data. I was trying to use "fseek()" but i can't do it right.
Here is what i have tried:

```
void take_exam()
{
    int id_temp;
    int n,sum=0;
    char answer[20];
    printf("Choose the subject:\n");
    printf("1.Math\n");
    printf("2.English\n");
    printf("3.Physics\n");
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    FILE *finside;
    finside=fopen(name_student,"rb+"); //open the student file. The students are registered in ab+ mode
    if(finside==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in file");
        return;
    }
    
    switch (n)//used switch case for the different subjects
    {
        case 1:
        FILE *f;
        f=fopen(name_math,"rb");//opened the math file, where i have stored the question and answers
        if(f==NULL)
        {
         printf("Error in file");
            return; 
        }
        while(fread(&math,sizeof(struct subject),1,f))
{
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter your ID");
        scanf("%d",&id_temp);
        printf("====Start the exam=====\n");

    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)// I have done each exam with 6 questions
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nQuestion number %d\n",i);
        printf("%s\n",math.q[i].question);
        printf("%s\n",math.q[i].ans1);
        printf("%s\n",math.q[i].ans2);
        printf("%s\n",math.q[i].ans3);
        printf("%s\n",math.q[i].ans4);
    
        printf("Give your answer:");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c",answer);

        // The part of points calculate fine
        if(strcmp(math.q[i].answer,answer)==0)
        {
            sum++;
        }
        else if(strcmp(math.q[i].ans4,answer)==0)
        {
            sum=+0;
        }
        else if((strcmp(math.q[i].answer,answer)!=0) && (strcmp(math.q[i].ans4,answer)!=0))
        {
            sum--;
        }
        
    math.q[i].points=sum;
    }
    printf("The exam is over!");}
        printf("You got %d points",sum);
    while(fread(&s[nr_student],sizeof(struct stud),1,finside))
        {
        fseek(finside,sizeof(struct stud),SEEK_SET);//The points are stored in this part but that student 
        if(s[nr_student].ID==id_temp)               // is repeated again. One with the primary points
        {                                           // and the other one with the points he's got.
            s[nr_student].points+=sum;
        }
        fwrite(&s[nr_student],sizeof(struct stud),1,finside);
    }
    fclose(finside);
    fclose(f);
    break;
case 2:
*** //and so on for the other subjects
```

The output i get:
ID: 1
Name:John
Points:0

ID:1
Name:John
Points:6

ID:2
Name:Bill
Points:0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the number in the file only if it occupies exactly the same number of bytes. But if that is the case, then your strategy could be:

1. `ftell` the current position
2. read the next record
3. compare it with the record you want.
4. if it is the right one, then `fseek` to the position you got from `ftell`
5. write the record.

Comment: Hey @Paul i was trying to do what you said but it didn't work. Maybe i'm doing it wrong,high possibility, but when i try it, the program keep finding the last record and doesn't replace it but append another one with the same data like the one i wanted to change(the integer i wanted was replaced). The student file was opened in append mode. Do u think thus might be the problem? Thanks again

Comment: Your opening of `"rb+"` is correct. It means "open for reading and writing without CR/LF translation". But you must have an intermittent `fseek` before writing, otherwise it will write at the end. Carefully read the documentation of fseek, fwrite, and fopen!

Comment: @Peter thanks, I just realized how i was using wrong fseek and now works fine.